# Is it possible Call method javascript from android without webview?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, websocket

In my android app need to call javascript function. if i call from android using webview work fine.
but i want to call without webview,i working with android as client and node.js as server, i want communicate both without webview.

for example in my javascript i have this function

```
function test(){
    //script for insert data here
}
```

I want calling **test function** from android without webview, how to achieve that? what should i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2018:** AndroidJSCore has been superseded by [LiquidCore](https://github.com/LiquidPlayer/LiquidCore), which is based on V8.  Not only does it include the V8 engine, but all of Node.js is available as well.

**Original Answer**:
See [AndroidJSCore](https://github.com/ericwlange/AndroidJSCore).  It is a full port of JavaScriptCore for Android, and runs JavaScript without a bulky, slow WebView.

Sample Snippet:

```
JSContext context = new JSContext();
context.evaluateScript("a = 10");
JSValue newAValue = context.property("a");
System.out.println(df.format(newAValue.toNumber())); // 10.0
String script =
  "function factorial(x) { var f = 1; for(; x > 1; x--) f *= x; return f; }\n" +
  "var fact_a = factorial(a);\n";
context.evaluateScript(script);
JSValue fact_a = context.property("fact_a");
System.out.println(df.format(fact_a.toNumber())); // 3628800.0
```

Docs: http://ericwlange.github.io/

Comment: Do note that AndroidJSCore library is huge (40MB big). The developer is currently looking for ways to reduce the footprint.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) to run javascripts in java or [Rhino](http://divineprogrammer.blogspot.com/2009/11/javascript-rhino-on-android.html) library.